# DPLYR SQL Left Join

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I have this one from SQL but i don't know how to deliver with dplyr in R.
I try but the column that I hope not like that

```
select a.*, b.*, c.FLAG, c.MONTH, c.DATE from APPLICATION a 
left join CURL b on a.NO = b.NO 
left join WO c on a.NO = c.NO
```

Can you fixed this?

```
ab <- APPLICATION %>% left_join(CURL, by = c("NO" = "NO")) %>% 
                      left_join(WO , by = c("NO" = "NO"))  %>%
                      select(names(APPLICATION), names(CURL), FLAG, MONTH, DATE)
```

Comment: I would put the `WO` column selection inside the join, `left_join(select(WO, NO, FLAG, MONTH, DATE))`. Then you can omit the other `select()` line, and it should be good.

Comment: so it will be 
ab <- APPLICATION %>% left_join(CURL, by = c("NO" = "NO")) %>% 
                      left_join(select(WO, NO, FLAG, MONTH, DATE) , by = c("NO" = "NO")) .

Is it okay we select that because i dont select NO column?

Comment: Don't take my word for it, test it! But the `NO` column is selected because it's the column your joining on, so it is in all 3 data frames.

Answer (score -1):

If the column you are joining on has the same name NO, you need not write `by=c('NO'='NO')`. Just `by='NO'`  should be enough.

Comment: Ummm ... `by=c("NO"="NO")` produces the exactly same results as `by="NO"`. (Part of me wonders if internally the latter is converted to the former ... but not enough to actually wade through the code.)

Comment: This seems a lot like a comment and not an answer, more of a "FYI" type thing.